# Sorting non-english characters in multilingual website

Tags: i18n-l10n, views

> I'm having an issue with finding good approach to make sorting works
>   in a Drupal Views.
>
> I've multilingual website (1 database for all languages). Few
>   languages are sorted wrong.
>
> I've read that the real issue is on database layer, however I can't set
>   any specific encoding there, since database contains many different
>   languages.
>
> What would be the most correct approach to make sorting works?
>   The minimum I need atm is a sorting in a Drupal Views.

Any good approach of solving such issues?

Comment: I think that until you've sorted out things on the db layer, this question is going to be off-topic. Check what encoding you currently have on your db, and do some research on that topic. Then you can move the focus to "How can I get Views to handle X as Y", which would be on-topic.

Comment: @letharion I agree, that 'right' solution must be done on db layer, however I think it is to late (I would be happy to be wrong), since we have only 1 database for all languages for almost 1 year. What would you recommend me to do in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to somebody.

I end up with doing a simple module (which I'm gonna improve later) that inject COLLATE while doing query to Database so it sort everything properly.

Please feel free to comment this solution :)

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 *
 * it adds 'COLLATE utf8_language_ci' to languages that are not supported by default
 * so far there are only few languages we have issues with.
 */
function views_collate_sorting_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  // views where we want to enable collation
  $views = array(
    'dictionary_overview'
  );

  // exit if the current view is not specified
  if (!in_array ($view->name, $views)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // define list of languages we support
  $map = array(
    'da' => 'utf8_danish_ci',
    'sv' => 'utf8_swedish_ci',
    'nb' => 'utf8_danish_ci',
    'es' => 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    'pl' => 'utf8_polish_ci',
  );

  // get current utf8
  $l = $GLOBALS['language']->language;

  if (!array_key_exists ($l, $map)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // get current utf8 language which we are going to add to all sort fields
  $utf8 = $map[$l];

  // add COLLATE utf8_xx_ci to all sort criteria
  $orderby = &$query->orderby;
  foreach ($orderby as &$order) {
    $order['field'] .= ' COLLATE ' . $utf8;
  }
}
```